# Select dinámico de categorías - Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, html-select

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel 8, donde necesito que el superadmin pueda crear una categoría y seleccionarle una categoría padre, teniendo en cuenta que cada tienda tiene sus propias categorías. Entonces necesito hacer 2 select: el primero que seleccione la tienda a la cual va a pertenecer y el segundo que sea dinámico, donde se muestren solo las categorías de la tienda seleccionada previamente.

### create.blade.php

```
<label for="tienda_id">Tienda</label>
<select id="tienda_id" name="tienda_id" class="custom-select">                 
@foreach($tiendas as $tienda)
   <option value="{{ $tienda->id}}">{{ $tienda->nombre}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

<label for="cat_padre">Categoría padre</label>
<select  id="cat_padre" name="cat_padre" class="custom-select">                                              
</select>
```

### Tabla categorias

| id | tienda_id | cat_padre | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

### Tabla tiendas

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |

### CategoriaController.php

```
public function create()
    {              
      $tiendas = Tienda::all();
      $categorias = Categoria::all();                    

      $datos = [            
        'tiendas' => $tiendas,
        'categorias' => $categorias
      ];

    return view('categoria.create')->with($datos);
    }
```

### web.php

```
Route::resource('/categorias', 'App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController');
```

### Categoria.php (modelo)

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','tienda_id','cat_padre'];

    public function tienda(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tienda');
    }

    public function subcategorias(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Categoria', 'cat_padre');
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 tienda tiene N categorias, entonces en tu modelo tienda:

```
class Tienda extends Model
{
   public function categorias()
   {
    return $this->hasMany(Categoria::class);
   }
}
```

en tu funcion create() de tu controlador llamaras a todas tus **tiendas** con sus N **categorias** de esta manera.

```
public function create()
{
    $tiendas = Tienda::with('categorias')->get();

    return view('categoria.create')->with($tiendas);
}
```

no conosco mucho blade hasta aqui llegue , pero creo que con otro for each podrias leer las categorias de la tienda seleccionada.

Comment: Claro, con eso no tengo problema, el tema es hacer el select con javascript para que muestre solo las categorías de la tienda seleccionada prviamente y no todas.